# We found out that we made an illegal move later on in the game

Tags: rules, illegal-move

I am playing with my friend. I didn't notice that my king was in check, so I made an illegal move. We noticed this after several more moves.

What should happen next? Do we restart the game or continue it as is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I made an illegal move. What happens?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/181/i-made-an-illegal-move-what-happens) and [What happens if a player makes an illegal move and nobody notices?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/22701/what-happens-if-a-player-makes-an-illegal-move-and-nobody-notices) and [llegal Move Missed — Too Late?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19972/illegal-move-missed-too-late)

Answer (score 11):

FIDE Laws of Chess 7.4a

> If during a game it is found that an illegal move, ..., has
>   been completed, the position immediately before the irregularity shall be
>   reinstated. If the position immediately before the irregularity cannot be determined
>   the game shall continue from the last identifiable position prior to the irregularity.
>   The clocks shall be adjusted according to Article 6.13. The Articles 4.3 and 4.6 [touch move] apply
>   to the move replacing the illegal move. The game shall then continue from this reinstated position.

Of course, if you are playing with your friend, you can choose to do whatever you feel would be best. The above is simply what would happen in a FIDE tournament.

Comment: The rules are a bit different for USCF - if it's been more than 10 moves, the illegal move stays and play continues.